# What grade does Bob need on his final to pass his math class?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Bob's teacher has a syllabus where the grading breakdown is as follows:

- Homework: 10%
- Tests (2): 60%
- Final Exam: 30%

- Bob receives all 10% from the homework
- Bob receives 78/100 on Test 1 (78%)
- Bob receives 94/100 on Test 2 (94%)

What grade does Bob need on the final exam to get an A in the class (Assuming an A is 90-100%)?

---

I'm having troubles with Test 1 and Test 2. How do I find out how much percent out of 60 they get?

Comment: What's getting you stuck about this problem? Have you tried anything? Can you solve similar problems? We can't very much help you if you give us so little idea about what's making it hard for you.

Comment: I'm having troubles with Test 1 and Test 2. How do I find out how much percent out of 60 they get?

Comment: Does your name happen to be bob? :p

Comment: No my name is not bob, LOL.(edit: not that there is anything wrong with being named bob)

Comment: @user234474 Well, consider that the weight of each test is half of the 60% - so, each test is worth 30% of the final grade. (Alternatively, their total score on tests is the average of 78% and 94% - which is 86%, so you get 86% of the 60%)

Comment: So 86% of 60 = 51.6 is the score of the two tests combined is 51.6/60.

Comment: @user234474 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Then the homework adds 10 to the 51.6, so it becomes 61.6/70. He would need to get 28.4/30 on the final to get an A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all weighted grades.

Homework Average: 100
Test Average: 86

Homework Weighted Average: $100\times0.10=10$
Test Weighted Average: $86\times0.6=51.6$

$\therefore (100\times0.10)+(86\times0.60)+(x\times0.30)=90$

Solve for $x$:

$x=94.7\therefore$ Bob must get at least a 95% on the final exam to get an A in the course